# How to catch the error code 422 in async await and display an error message to the user

Tags: error-handling, async-await, next.js

I want to render an error message when the user clicks on the plan button he is currently subscribed to.

Somehow I am not able to catch the error code 422 and massage the error response in such a way that when the user clicks the same button, a call is made to the API and the API throws the message "You are already subscribed to the plan.

How can I catch the error code 422 and display the error message? Here is the code:

```
const [updating, setUpdating] = useState(false);
const [change, setChange] = useState(null);

const changeSubscription = async (change) => {
  setChange(change);
  setUpdating(true);
  try {
    const update = await fetch('/subscription', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: 'token',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        stripe_subscription_id: user.subscription.items[0].id,
        product_id: tier.id,
        proration_date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
      }),
    });
    await update.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: So are you successful in logging the 422 error in the `catch` block? Or is that not being caught but the code you shared?

Comment: @RyanM - I am not able to catch the error. In console, it is giving me the error code but I am trying to display the same error message to the user.

Comment: What I mean is, you are seeing the error in the console, right?  That means your `catch(error)` block is working to catch the error.  So then you would just need to return the error message or some transformed version of it to your front-end instead of the subscription data.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an `errMsg` state to store the string representing the error and display it when not empty:

```
const [updating, setUpdating] = useState(false);
const [change, setChange] = useState(null);
const [errMgs, setErrMsg] = useState('');

const changeSubscription = async (change) => {
  setChange(change);
  setUpdating(true);
  setErrMsg(''); // Reset error
  try {
    const update = await fetch('/subscription', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        token: 'token',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        stripe_subscription_id: user.subscription.items[0].id,
        product_id: tier.id,
        proration_date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
      }),
    });
    await update.json();
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error
    if (error.response.status === 422) {
        setErrMsg('You are already subscribed to the plan')
    } else setErrMsg('Generic error')
  }
};

return (
    // Display error message if present
    {errMsg !== '' && <>{errMsg}</>}
    // Rest of JSX
    ...
)
```